# Alternative to dense_rank in sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, dense-rank

is there a way to rebuild the `dense_rank` function in Sybase ASE?

So I would need a unique number for every tuple (foo, bar).

Table:

```
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| a   | a   |
| a   | b   |
| a   | c   |
| a   | c   |
| b   | a   |
| b   | a   |
+-----+-----+
```

Result:

```
+-----+-----+------+
| foo | bar | rank |
+-----+-----+------+
| a   | a   |    1 |
| a   | b   |    2 |
| a   | c   |    3 |
| a   | c   |    3 |
| b   | a   |    4 |
| b   | a   |    4 |
+-----+-----+------+
```

How can I do this without the `dense_rank` function?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following subquery should provide the same functionality:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(distinct foo + ':' + bar)
        from table t2
        where t2.foo < t.foo or
              t2.foo = t.foo and t2.bar < t.bar
       ) as rank
from table t;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! But how does the `1 +`ever make a difference? It seems to me it works well even without that

Comment: @WilliFischer . . . `dense_rank()` starts counting at 1 and not 0.